# ExactTarget File Move

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have to move a csv file from the ftp import directory to a archive directory after it's done performing the import activity.  How can we achieve this within ExactTarget?

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable "Enhanced FTP File Move and Copy." by contacting support. Then configure the data extract to move from one folder to another.

reference link - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000230276&type=1

[image]

Comment: Where is this screenshot found inside of Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it (and I'm having some issues with my ET FTP, so I've not been able to test this, lamentably)  You will need to have administrator rights on your ET account first.  Then:

1. Go into the Admin tab, under the Email Application.
2. Choose File locations.
3. Choose External FTP site (or SFTP if you need to), EVEN IF ExactTarget is your final file destination
4. In the URL, put in the full path to that directory.
5. Navigate next to Interactions -> File Transfer.  Select Upload, fill in the rest.
6. Put them all together in a program or in AutomationStudio so that they run sequentially.  Instead of running just the import now, you need to run this automation
7. WEEE!  Success.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Timothy.  I have created a Program that contains 2 activities: Import and File Transfer.  In the Import activity, the FTP Location is set to Import directory, and File Transfer's FTP Location is set to Export.  I tried both Upload and Download option and it always fail on the File Transfer step.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer is not correct, at least in our account. File Transfer activity does not allow you to set a destination, only a source.

Comment: you might need to do this via file transfers in Email Studio instead of automation studio - and I'm not sure if you need to download first and then upload - but the options to do the desired operation is there (ping Jon Sakas)